# Release element from z-index deadlock

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using two different jquery plugins (pickadate.js and EasyAutocomplete) on two input fields. These plugins do create a position:absolute overlay, relative to the attached input fields.

My problem is, that my cms theme uses massive position relative/absolute constructions and at different page positions these plugin overlays either get truncated by overflow:hidden or reside under other theme elements and increasing the z-index doesn't help. The theme authors can't help me, it's too complex.

Is there a CSS way to release an element from this z-index respectively position:relative/absolute cage? 
Alternatively I could create a hidden element in the top level of the markup and move both plugin overlay objects to this element, before they become visible. Some plugins do allow to attach the overlay to a manually created div. These unfortunately not.

So is it possible with jquery to move an element and all of it's plugin logic to another parent element and make it appear at the same position, right under the assigned input fields?

Comment: You could use `position: static` on the element which will cause the element to ignore the `z-index`. By default all HTML elements are `static`.

Comment: if the parent doesn't have a `z-index`, you can use a negative `z-index` on the child to put it behind the parent - not sure if that helps or not. hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the code, did you try to play with positioning and z-index through Developer tools on chrome?

Comment: I've already tried position:static/fixed and a negative z-index.